# Find the number of ways to park cars next to each other in a parking area

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations, factorial

Question is;

> Find the number of ways to park $4$ cars next to each other in a
>   parking area with $10$ distinct places to park if:
>
> (A) The parking area is in the shape of a circle.
>
> (B) The parking area is in the form of a rows.
>
> Given answers: (A)$240$ (B)$168$

How do I solve it and what is the concept behind the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parking area is a circle, there are $4!$ ways to have the cars permuted. As the cars must all be parked next to each other, they form a "block" of $4$ cars. Pick an arbitrary car. There are $10$ possible positions it can take in the circle. Thus, the amount of ways is $4! \cdot 10 = 240$.

---

If the parking area is a row of $10$, again there is $4!$ ways to permute the order of the cars. The cars form a contiguous "block" of $4$. Pick the leftmost car. It may be in positions $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$(it can't be $8,9,10$ because there are $3$ cars to the right of it). These give $7$ total placements of the block of four. Thus, the amount of ways is $4! \cdot 7 = 168$.

Comment: So in circle the general formula would be;
 $Cars!*Lots$

and in row it would be;
 $(Lots-Cars+1'the leftmost car')*Cars! $
Is that true?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I don't know why you included "the leftmost car" in the expression, barring that everything is fine.

Comment: err i meant that the one represents the selected car, which is the leftmost one here

Comment: In general, the leftmost car will not have that position. I used that as an extreme case to count how many spots there were.

Comment: I understand now, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints.

- How many places can you place four cars next to each other in each configuration? (A picture may help a lot.)
- For each one of those places, how many ways can you arrange the four cars?

Can you take it from here?